# C++: Alternative to this range's view construction with same requirements?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

To remove manual logic in my code, I use that construct:

```
std::ranges::drop_view a { std::ranges::take_view(my_range, my_range.size() -X), Y};
```

with X and Y values I pass at runtime.

Even though I check the algorithms, I could not find a shorter way that has the following constraints:

1. don't go beyond or below the range I want, and don't do anything if the range has 0 elements -> no overflow
2. non owning -> no copies

ranges::subranges doesn't meet those requirements.

Thanks

Comment: There's really no reason to write `drop_view` and `take_view` in code. This is: `auto a = my_range | views::take(my_range.size() - X) | views::drop(Y)`. Or `auto a = views::drop(views::take(my_range, my_range.size() - X), Y);` Note that `views::take(r, n)` isn't always a `take_view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose `take_view` and `drop_view` into a new adaptor

```
auto take_and_drop = [](auto n, auto m) {
  return std::views::take(n) | std::views::drop(m);
};

auto a = my_range | take_and_drop(my_range.size() - X, Y);
```

Comment: `my_range.size() - X` has type `std::size_t`, so if `X > size()`, you don't have expected behaviour (`n` would have big value instead of negative one).

Comment: @Jarod42: that case is already handled by the library by checking the length of the container. No issues here: U(ranges::begin(e), ranges::begin(e) + std::min<D>(ranges::distance(e), f))

Comment: @Kroma: I would expect an empty view when `X > size()`, not a full view or UB.